# Continuity of functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an unital C*-Algebra. $a,b$ be normal elements in $\mathcal{A}$. $X\subset \Bbb C$ is a compact subset. $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb C$ is continuous.  I need to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $||f(a)-f(b)||<\epsilon$ whenever $||a-b||<\delta$ with $\sigma (a), \sigma (b)\subset X$.

I have no clue on how to attack the problem as I know to define $f(a)$ by considering $C^*(a)$. Now that I have to work with both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ I cannot use gelfand transformation directly. I tried to look at the definition of $f(a)$ and tried to write the map $f:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ explicitly that is giving all the identifications a name. But it got complicated and I could not work. Can you show me a way?

Comment: What is $f $? If $f $ is continuous, you could try to approximate it by polynomials in $z,\overline {z} $ Using Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: Sorry for that. editing it

Comment: Are you saying that it is enough to consider f to be a polynomial in  z,z¯ ?

Comment: Use the '@' symbol in front of the user name in order to ping them when you ask a question. Otherwise, they won't know you're asking them anything. This pings you because I'm posting under your question. If you post under someone's answer, then they will be pinged automatically, but they'll have to use @Kaushik to ping you back when they respond under their own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $f$ and $\epsilon$, choose a polynomial $p$ with $\Vert f-p\Vert_{\infty,X}<\epsilon$ (where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty,X}$ is the supremum norm *oin $X$*). Now see the corresponding polynomial function in $\mathcal{A}$, $p:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$. (Remember: the functional calculus respects this notation, i.e., $p(a)$, in the functional calculus, is obtained simply by plugging $a$ inside the polynomial $p$.) This is continuous, so, given $a\in\mathcal{A}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\Vert b-a\Vert<\delta$ implies $\Vert p(b)-p(a)\Vert<\epsilon$.

Now let's use the fact that injective $*$-homomorphisms are isometric: If $\sigma(b)\subseteq $ and $\Vert b-a\Vert<\delta$, then

\begin{align*}
\Vert f(a)-f(b)\Vert&\leq\Vert f(a)-p(a)\Vert+\Vert p(a)-p(b)\Vert+\Vert p(b)-f(b)\Vert\\
&=\Vert f-p\Vert_{\infty,\sigma(a)}+\Vert p(a)-p(b)\Vert+\Vert f-p\Vert_{\infty,\sigma(b)}\\
&\leq 2\Vert f-p\Vert_{\infty,X}+\Vert p(a)-p(b)\Vert<3\epsilon,
\end{align*}
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\infty,\sigma(a)}$ is the supremum norm *on $\sigma(a)$* and similarly for $\sigma(b)$.

With this, you can then show that the map on two variables $C(X)\times\left\{a\in\mathcal{A}:\sigma(a)\subseteq X\right\}\to\mathcal{A}$, $(f,a)\mapsto f(a)$, is continuous.